# Bookmark Lookups - How efficient is the lookup using a row pointer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll use this simple query as an example:
`Select MyColumn From MyTable Where PrimaryKeyColumn = 10`.

Let's assume the table has no clustered index and there is a primary key on `PrimaryKeyColumn`.

If I understand correctly, the query plan will include an index seek on the primary key and a bookmark lookup on the table, using some sort of row pointer. I have two questions:

1) What is this row pointer?

2) How efficient is finding a row in the table using this row pointer?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bookmark on a heap (a table w/o a clustered index) is a physical address value (fileid:pageid:slotid). Looking up the bookmark is really fast, faster than a key seek in fact, but one *may* land on a '[forwarded record](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Forwarding-and-forwarded-records-and-the-back-pointer-size.aspx)', which left in place another bookmark to follow, when you rinse cycle and repeat the process. Having plans that do non-clustered index *scans* that would require large volume lookups may trigger the '[index tipping point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Tipping-Point-Query-Answers.aspx)'.

Comment: Agreed.  Also keep in mind that index pages have a much higher chance of remaining in memory for long periods of time than heap data pages, so RID lookups may lead to more I/O, especially when forwarded records are involved.